# Ruby class variables in dynamic anonymous module

Tags: ruby, module

I'm creating an anonymous module because I need it to be dynamic, but using class variables like in the example below doesn't work. I have this code:

```
class Filter

  def self.mod(var)
    # Creating anonymous module
    m = Module.new do
      def hello
        puts @var
      end

      def self.var=(var)
        @@var = var
      end

      def self.var
        @@var
      end

    end
    # Setting the class variable
    m.var = var
    m
  end
end

f1 = Filter.mod("hello")

puts f1.var # => hello

f2 = Filter.mod("goodbye")

puts f2.var # => goodbye
puts f1.var # => goodbye
```

Why does f1 change when I assign to f2? I need each module to maintain its own variable values. Is there a way to circumvent this with anonymous / dynamic modules?

If I include the Filter in a class:

```
class Main
  include Filter.mod("hello")
end

m = Main.new

puts m.hello # => nil
```

How do I access the @var variable?

Comment: Fixed code formatting a bit :)

Comment: This is different from what I understood from your comments in that other question. Just use `@var` and `f1.var` won't change.

Comment: I didn't really know how to ask it, what am I looking for? A dynamic module? I updated the example. I'm trying to avoid values being changed on all instances.

Comment: Perhaps, show your exact use-case and not a made-up one? Why do [*you think*] you need this module thing at all?

Comment: It's for adding Liquid template filters, I need current_site and current_user to be available dynamically in custom filters without possibility for race conditions: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2e0c24b192327bad4e91

Comment: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83135/http-stackoverflow-com-questions-31384587-ruby-class-variables-in-dynamic-anony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@@` defines a class variable on `Filter`, not on your new `Module` like you expect. You can see it with:

```
puts Filter.class_variables.inspect
# [:@@var]
```

This only exists once, and gets written to by every reference to `@@var` that happens in the scope of `Filter`.

What you really want is *class instance variables* on each of your `Module.new`s, which you do with just a single `@`. This defines `@var` on your new *instance* of the `Module` *class*.

```
  def self.var=(var)
    @var = var
  end

  def self.var
    @var
  end

# ...

puts f1.class
# Module
puts f1.instance_variables.inspect
# [:@var]

puts f2.var
# goodbye
puts f1.var
# hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Because you assign to `@@var` which is a class variable. Try changing it to `@var`.